# Include Google Play Services with Source Code?

Tags: android

My project is open source and implements features from Google Play Services such as location. I'm having trouble in that when I upload my project to GitHub for instance, when the project is downloaded onto another user's machine to be worked on, all the references to Google Play Services become 'cannot be resolved' errors. Even uploading and redownloading the source on my own machine which has the Google Play Services SDK results in errors. Apparently the source code needs to be manually linked to the Google Play Services SDK each time it is imported to a different machine.

Is there a way to include the Google Play Services code in the source without requiring each user that downloads it to manually set up the Google Play Services SDK?

Comment: no you cant get the source code and if you are using `gradle dependencies` all the other person has to do is download the google repo in the sdk manager

Comment: Switch to Android Studio and refer to the Play Services SDK via a dependency in your `build.gradle` file. Note that you do not have the source code for the Play Services SDK, unless you work for Google.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/owncloud/android/blob/master/SETUP.md

This is a setup guide of another app. in it you can see `setup_env` scripts. You can have a solution like this and write a setup guide like this one for users who want to build.

Comment: Since it is an open source project multiple setup options like this is a good thing